# Can't understand script to create album, and upload photo to facebook fan page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, photos

I'm following this tutorial, http://www.webspeaks.in/2012/02/create-album-and-upload-photo-to.html to upload a photo to a facebook fan page album. The album is also created by the script.

But, the problem is that I can't understand somethings, or facebook changed the process, and the tutorial is not updated.

According to the tutorial, this page: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Faccounts should return a json data, with the token.

But this, is the kind of data that I get, and it shows only Apps, not Fan Pages.
    {
      "name": "app name", 
      "category": "Application", 
      "id": "appid"
    }

Another doubt, is that, if I want to upload photos to a facebook fan page, what should I put on these lines?

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
 'appId'  => '<app_id>',
 'secret' => '<app_sercret>',
 'fileUpload' => true
));
```

I can't understand this. I really need to setup a new application, that will be used to upload the photos to the fan page?

Thanks for any clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Your must add permisson "manage_pages" when your access  token, if your want to get list of fun page in answer.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(  'appId'  => '<app_id>',  'secret' =>
'<app_sercret>',  'fileUpload' => true ));
```

You must create your own application, if your want to use grap api - https://developers.facebook.com/apps